# Can't boot Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I've installed ubuntu using live CD. But when I turn my computer on, it starts windows 7 instead of giving me right to make a decision, which OS I need to boot. I think I have some problems with GRUB - it isn't run.

Comment: Try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

If you installed using a USB then try booting with the USB connected, if you see grub and can boot Ubuntu then have a look at [this guide on our website](http://fernhilllinuxproject.com/guidesandhowtos/bootrepair.html) for details of how to resolve the problem. :o)

Let us know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Grub organises two OSs on one Harddrive, you seem to have W7 in the harddrive and Ubuntu on a CD - so tell your BIOS to boot from CD.

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1 - From a Ubuntu Live CD

Open up a Terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>; we'll run a few commands.

---

First, identify which is the Ubuntu partition:

```
sudo fdisk -l | grep -iR linux | grep -viR swap
```

This should return a line like the following:

```
/dev/sda1   *          63    77144129    38572033+  83  Linux
```

- In this example, the partition identifier is `/dev/sda1`.

---

Mount this partition.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

- Replace `/dev/sda1` with the partition identifier you identified earlier.

---

Reinstall Grub.

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

- Replace `/dev/sda` with the appropriate hard drive identifier. This is the Ubuntu partition's identifier, without the trailing number.

---

Reboot your computer, this time without the Live CD.

### Step 2 - From the installed Ubuntu

If all went well in the previous step, you should now be logged into Ubuntu.

---

Once again, open up Terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>.

---

Now, run this:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This should detect your Windows installation and automatically add it to the Grub menu.

### You're done!

Reboot.

---

To make the Grub menu show up if it doesn't by default, hold the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key during the boot-up process. You'll then be able to select which OS you'd like to boot into.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)'s `Recommended Repair` to reinstall GRUB in 1 click. It will also provide a BootInfo summary if you need more help.

[image]